# Polymorphism and type conversion

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm confused about an aspect of polymorphism. Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class CBase {
    virtual void dummy() {}
};
class CDerived: public CBase {
    public:
    int a,b,c,d;
    CDerived (): a(1),b(2),c(3),d(4) { }
};
int main () {

    CBase* pba = new CDerived;

    std::cout << "sizeof(CBase) = " << sizeof(CBase) << std::endl; // prints 8
    std::cout << "sizeof(CDerived) = " << sizeof(CDerived) << std::endl; // prints 24

    std::cout << "sizeof(*pba) = " << sizeof(*pba) << std::endl; // prints 8 (?)

    return 0;
}
```

My question is the following: on the line `CBase* pba = new CDerived;` an object of `CDerived` type (24 bytes) is allocated, but as you can see, `sizeof(*pba) = 8` bytes. What happened to the other 16 bytes of the `CDerived` object pointed by `pba`? I also tried this:

```
std::cout << "pba->a = " << pba->a << std::endl;
```

but then got compilation errors, meaning `pba` really does not point to an object of type `CDerived`. So what happened here? Memory leak?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sizeof` is a compile-time construct. It can't know the runtime type, so it only considers the compile-time type, which is `CBase&`.

`pba->a` doesn't compile for similar reasons: the compile-time type of `pba` is `CBase*`, and `CBase` doesn't have an `a` member. This is how static typed languages work. If you want to use `CDerived` members, you need a variable with type `CDerived` (or a reference or pointer to it).

However, *the `CDerived` object is still there*. You can see that if you convert the pointer to a pointer to `CDerived`, like `dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pba)->a`.

Comment: Though the Q is only marked C++, Worthwhile to mention that in C, `sizeof` can evaluate size of objects at runtime like that of variable length arrays(allowed in C unlike C++).

Comment: I actually got it by using `static_cast`: `std::cout << static_cast<CDerived*>(pba) << std::endl;` compiles and prints the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` return the size of the static type of an object, and since `pba` is a `CBase*`, the static type of `*pba` is `CBase`, whose size is `8` (no data members and a `vfptr`).\

> [...] meaning pba really does not point to an object of type CDerived

it does, but you can't access `CDerived` specific members through a pointer to `CBase`.

Assume I hand you over a `CBase*` and tell you to access the member `a`. You can't. You can't be sure it's a pointer to a `CDerived` and has that member, or to some other derived class (unless you use RTTI). **It doesn't make sense logically** to access derived class members through a base class pointer.

Comment: That answers part of the question, but some stuff is missing. If I actually  made `pba` point to an object of type `CDerived`, whose size is bigger than 8 bytes, than how do I access the members of this `Cderived` through `pba`?